# Best way to utilise push notifications when app goes into background

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a React Native developer currently working on a vehicle tracking app.

We want to develop a feature that allows users to exit the app, but continually be updated in the form of notifications when the vehicle moves (on average every 60 seconds).

I have been tasked with coming up the best way of integrating this. Our app already has push notifications set up with Firebase and we do use this to push out generic messages to the app.

My thinking is as follows:

When a user begins tracking a vehicle, the app should subscribe to a Firebase topic identified as the vehicle's registration. On the server side, each time an update comes in for a vehicle, send out a Firebase notification to that vehicle registration's topic, and then any users tracking it will be updated. When a user returns to the app and presses 'Stop tracking', the app unsubscribes from the topic.

In theory I think this would work. The reason I'm posting is I'm not sure it's the most efficient way. Our server received updates for over 1,000 vehicles every minute.

Any help/ideas would be gratefully received!

Comment: Interesting. "allows users to exit the app", the tracked user and tracking user can exit the app? I'm not sure the exited app can send out anything.